# Kivy:- Load & Save does not work for pdf & word docment

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I was reading the kivy pdf file & in that i found a Load & Save code...That code works well for .txt file & .py file but it does not work for .docx & .pdf file...

main.py:---

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

import os

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    #text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    #text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        print(self.load)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        print(self.save)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()


    def load(self, path, filename):

        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:

            self.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=Label(text = 'File Loaded Successfully'), size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()




    def save(self, path, filename):

        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:

            stream.write(self.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()

        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=Label(text = 'File Saved Successfully'), size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

class Editor(App):
    pass


Factory.register('Root', cls=Root)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

editor.kv:---

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

Root:
    #text_input: text_input

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            Button:
                text: 'Load'
                on_release: root.show_load()
            Button:
                text: 'Save'
                on_release: root.show_save()


        Image:
            source: 'myimage.png'

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)
```

Which part of the code i should modify so that it will work for all type of files...????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.docx` and `.pdf` are not text-based formats. You can load `.txt` and `.py` files because they are text-based. What you're doing is essentially like trying to load a `.png` as text - `.png` is a binary format, just like `.docx` and `.pdf`.

In order to display `.docx`, you would need to learn the file format and write your own loader, or use an existing loader. A quick Google search turns up [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Once you've loaded the file, if you want it displayed then you will need to write your own code to display it in Kivy, or convert it to a format which Kivy already supports, like reStructuredText.

Similarly, for `.pdf`, Google finds [pyPdf2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/). Again, you would need to convert it to rST or generate Kivy widgets/instructions to display the document yourself.

Comment: is there any way to convert a .docx file to .txt file & vica versa...@Ryan P

Comment: @VishalParmar You could try using LibreOffice/OpenOffice to convert the documents. Something like `soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text YOUR-DOCUMENT-HERE.DOC` [from here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Gd1D-OO4pIUJ:ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1671/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-convert-documents-to-plain-text-files/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).